# Create a Powershell ListBox Sticky Notes Backup Utility

Tags: powershell, winforms, listbox

I'm building a PowerShell utility that will backup and restore sticky notes using a powershell script to pull the Get-localuser command from a local device into the list box. From list box choose the user profile and it initiates a comand to fetch a file. What im researching is after you select a user in list box, it sends a command to copy a file Thank you.

Example: Admin is the user:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe c:\users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\pause copy plum.sqlite-wal cd C:\Users\Admin\Documents\SN Utility
```

**working edited:** code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'StickyNotes Utility'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,120)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(185,120)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20)
$label.Text = 'Select a user to backup:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,20)
$listBox.Height = 80

$listbox.Items.AddRange((get-localuser | select -expand name))

$form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

do
{
    $result = $form.ShowDialog()

    if ($ListBox.SelectedIndices.Count -lt 1 -and $result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
        Write-Warning 'Nothing was selected, please select a user.'
    }
}
until (($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK -and $listBox.SelectedIndices.Count -ge 1) -or $result -ne [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)

{
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem
    
    $x
}
```

directory list inside list box

```
$subfolders = (Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory).FullName

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "SubFolders"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,180)
$listBox.Anchor = 'Top,Right,Bottom,Left' 

$listbox.Items.AddRange((get-localuser | select -expand name))

$listBox.Add_Click({
    $selected = $listBox.GetItemText($listBox.SelectedItem)
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You selected subfolder`r`n`r`n$selected", "Subfolder")
})

$form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: What's the question or where you need help ?

Comment: Santiago I modified the post to better explain what it is i need help with thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, i believe you want to replace the line

```
[void] $listBox.Items.AddRange(@("user1", "user2", "user3"))
```

with

```
Get-Localuser | select -expand name | foreach {[void] $listbox.Items.Add($_)}
```

or

```
$listbox.Items.AddRange((get-localuser | select -expand name))
```

Comment: Yes Robert that worked. Thank you

Comment: Ah, good. I'm glad it worked. If you believe my answer to be the official answer, it is polite and best practice to check it off as the answer, so other users can know what solved the problem.

Comment: Finally, the code inside the If block instructs Windows what to do with the form after a user is selected from an option from the list box, What do you suggest after selecting the user from the list box, how to navigate into the users profile folder to copy an item say from the users document folder, then after you click the OK button it completes the command or task? Thank you

Comment: This is a lot to explain. Simply put make a script block that does what you want. (Loop through selected users and perform actions) and then use `$button.add_click($scriptblock)` for your ok button to run it.

Comment: This is perfect. Appreciate the help Robert. Thank you.

Comment: So I'm going a different direction and adding a directory list into list box so it fills the list box with $listbox.Items.AddRange((get-localuser | select -expand name)) output and opens the users sub folder directory. See updated construct